# Subclassing QVector<T>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Here's my problem: I want to subclass QVector in order to add some function specific to my context.

Naive approach was:

```
class ClassVector : public QVector<Class> { ... }
```

But problem here is when I need to call one of few functions on QVector which return new QVector (or & to itself):

```
ClassVector cv1, cv2;
auto sum = cv1 + cv2;
```

This is valid **but** sum is QVector, since operator+ return QVector.

Is there simple way to make it return ClassVector somehow?

Calling reinterpret_cast on the result is not what I want to do :/

If it's important, I only add functions to ClassVector, no data members.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know about QVector, but not all classes are meant to be inherited. Can you add your functions as free-standing (or in a namespace)? Especially if you only add functions, and it has no virtual functions.

Comment: I'd recommend against subclassing `QVector`. Could you add your functions as free functions instead, since you apparently don't need to add state to the class? Alternatively, could you create your new class with a `QVector` as a member instead of a super class (this is called aggregation)?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing (free functions in namespace) but I was curious if there isn't any smarter way of doing this.. seems that it isn't :/

Comment: @Paladin [See also this question, which, while about C#, also applies to your scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: @milleniumbug ok, it sort of applies to my scenario, but not completely. OP over there asks if he should implement football team as subclass of list<T> while he wants to add new data to the class (score, ...). That's not my case. I only want to add few convenience functions (for example for QVector<Class> searching for item in vector by Class.foo). All of those are definitely doable by non-member functions, I just though it would be handy to have them directly on the vector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new `operator+` shall return a different type, you can of course re-implement it.

```
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>

class ClassVector : public QVector<int>
{
public:
    typedef QVector<int> base_type;

    ClassVector operator+ (const ClassVector& other) const
    {
        ClassVector sum(*this);
        static_cast<base_type&>(sum) += other;
        return sum;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClassVector cv1;
    cv1.append(1);
    cv1.append(2);
    cv1.append(3);
    ClassVector cv2;
    cv2.append(11);
    cv2.append(12);

    ClassVector sum = cv1 + cv2;

    for (auto&& v : sum)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Another option would be to have an implicit constructor for the conversion from `QVector<Class>` to `ClassVector`. Something like

```
class ClassVector : public QVector<int>
{
public:
    typedef QVector<int> base_type;

    ClassVector() {}

    // Allow to convert a QVector<int> into a ClassVector.
    ClassVector(const QVector<int>& other) : QVector<int>(other) {}

    // ... possibly other constructors + assignment operator
};
```

would also work in your case.

However, if you do not add new state to `ClassVector`, I would also go with a free function.

Comment: Can I also override __non-virtual__ functions like this?

Comment: Note that the example above has no virtual function in it. As long as you do not operate via a base class pointer (or reference), you can also overload non-virtual functions.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help :) I'm going with free functions, it just seems cleaner (and safer)